# make a node element and appending it

Tags: javascript

Supposed I am creating a node

```
   element.pics.forEach((pic, i) => {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 180;
            image.classList.add('mt-2','rounded','mr-2', 'w-100');
            image.src    = pic;
            i++;

            if (i <= 2) {
                oHome.oImageRow1.appendChild(image);
            } else {
                oHome.oImageRow2.appendChild(image);
            }

            console.log(i);
        });
```

before appending the image on oImageRow how can I wrap it inside a div with a class of col I tried

```
let html = `<div class="col"><img height="180" class="mt-2 rounded mr-2 w-100" src="${pic}"/></div>`;
```

and append it using

```
oHome.oImageRow1.appendChild(html);
```

However I got an error saying

> parameter 1 is not a type of node

Comment: Well, a mere string of text is not an actual HTML element node. You need to either use `innerHTML` if you want to assign HTML code as the new content of an element in string form and let the browser parse it; or you need to create actual elements and set their attributes, using the appropriate DOM methods (createElement, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment i got it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
let html = document.createElement('div')
html.classList.add('col')
html.innerHTML = '<img height="180" class="mt-2 rounded mr-2 w-100" src="${pic}"/>'

oHome.oImageRow1.appendChild(html)
```

You can only append DOM nodes, you tried to append a string.